# Recommendation: Starting a recursion function in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tweepy

My goal of this program is to create a Tweepy stream that funnels Tweets into a presentation style GUI with tkinter. Additionally, the presentation is ment to run continuously until i break the code looping through the tweets. In my GUI I have a function `change(n)` hat effectively changes the Tweet slide if you want to think about it that way.

I'm looking for a recommendation for where to start this recurring  function. Since I'm running in tkinter, I need to do it before `root.mainloop()`. However, if I call during `__init__`  or `initui()` it will never get to `root.mainloop()` as it will trigger once the app instance is called.

Code below:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import sleep

class listener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application

    def on_data(self, data):
        self.application.add(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="white")
        self.parent = parent

        global screen_h, screen_w
        screen_h = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        screen_w = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()

        global tweets
        tweets = ["Tweet with #2017"]

        self.parent.bind('<Escape><Escape>', self.close)
        self.initui()


    def initui(self):
        self.parent.title("2017")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        t = Image.open("twitter.jpg")
        t_ar = t.size[0]/t.size[1]
        t_h = int(screen_h*.1)
        t_w = int(t_h * t_ar)
        t = t.resize((t_w,t_h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        t = ImageTk.PhotoImage(t)

        logo = Label(self, image=t, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        logo.image = t
        position = ((screen_w*.1)-(t_w/2),(screen_h*.5)-(t_h/2))
        logo.place(x=position[0], y=position[1])


    def add(self, tweet):
        tweets.append(tweet)

    def change(self, n):
        tweet = tweets[n]
        label = Label(self, text=tweet, height=screen_h, width=int(screen_w*.75), anchor=CENTER, bg="white", font=("Helvetica", 24))
        label.pack(side=RIGHT)
        sleep(30)
        if n+2 <= len(tweets):
            label.destroy()
            self.change(n+1)
        else:
            label.destroy()
            self.change(0)

    def close(self, event):
        self.parent.destroy()


def run():
    #start the app
    root = Tk()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    start = app(root)

    #Twitter API keys
    consumer_key=""
    consumer_secret=""
    access_token=""
    access_token_secret=""

    #Start Twitter Stream
    l = listener(start)
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['basketball'], async=True)

    root.mainloop()

run()
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look at threads :) ?

Comment: do it without recursion - and without `sleep(30)` which will freeze `Tkinter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test your code but you could do this without recursion and without `sleep(30)` but using `after(miliseconds, function_name, argument)` - something like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    # create empty label only once
    self.label = Label(self, height=screen_h, width=int(screen_w*.75), anchor=CENTER, bg="white", font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.label.pack(side=RIGHT)

def change(self, n):

    # change only text
    self.label['text'] = tweets[n]

    n += 1

    if n == len(tweets):
        n = 0

    # or in one line
    # n = (n + 1) % len(tweets)

    # run again after 30000ms = 30s
    root.after(30000, self.change, n)
    #self.parent.after(30000, self.change, n)
```

And now you can start it before `mainloop()` and it will not freeze `Tkinter` because `after` sends it to `mainloop()` which will call `change()` after 30s.